# How to use enum type for a domain model in EF Model First?

Tags: entity-framework

We have been using enum type in a domain model for a while. But it is in a Code-First approach.

My new project has an existing edmx already. But in the Edmx Designer I cannot make a Type of my property use an **enum**.

So the question is, is it possible to use **enum** in a model-first approach?  How?

Comment: That article is about code-first.

Comment: do a rightclick on the entry in the model, here you can select to convert it to ENUM. But this depends on the EF version. You need version 5 (.net 4.5) or EF6 (.net 4.0)

Comment: Whoops, I copied the wrong link, sorry. Here is the one I meant to copy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772